# Get containt form patent window in child window

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, window

I want to create a child window in silverlight 4 but when the child window pop-up the parent window should not be disable.
I should able to access control or properties from parent window how do i do this.
Whether its possible?

Answer (score 0):

Set OverlayBrush property of ChildWindow to transparent color

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can find solution in FloatableWindow [here](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2009/05/10/silverlight-childwindow-non-modal-refactor.aspx).